# Writing basic BMI analysis program for python

Tags: python

I have run into an issue with an assignment, I have just been introduced to modules so I haven't quite got the hang of things yet,but this is my current code.

```
def main():
    weightlb = float(input("Enter your weight in pounds: "))
    heightin = float(input("Enter your height in inches: "))`

main()

def calcBMI():

   bmi = weightlb * 703/ heightin **2

print("Your BMI is", bmi)
calcBMI()
```

Every time I run this program as an attempt I come into this error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/BradH/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35-32/test.py", line 10, in 
>       calcBMI()
>     File "C:/Users/BradH/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35-32/test.py", line 7, in calcBMI
>       bmi = weightlb * 703/ heightin **2
>   NameError: name 'weightlb' is not defined`

I would appreciate any assistance with my coding errors I must have made

Comment: Can you explain what you think is happening? I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do with this code by breaking it up into so many functions. First of all, there are no modules in your code. Second, you'll want to use `return` to return values from functions. There are a lot more things to point out but I would like to hear more about your goal before we delve into that.

Comment: Basically trying to make a basic BMI calculator and I am supposed to separate it into two different modules, one for defining the variables and one for using them to find the BMI

Answer (score -1, accepted):

your code should be like this:

```
def calcBMI(weightlb, heightin):
   bmi = weightlb * 703/ heightin **2
   return bmi

def main():
    weightlb = float(input("Enter your weight in pounds: "))
    heightin = float(input("Enter your height in inches: "))`
    bmi = calcBMI(weightlb, heightin)
    print("Your BMI is %f" %bmi)

main()
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, I see now that I needed to use the 'return' command in order for it to work. You were the only REAL help here

Answer (score 1):

Variables in Python have what is called scope. At a basic level, they only last inside their function call. So, once main returns, weightlb is no longer defined.

This looks to be a pretty decent primer: http://python-textbok.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Variables_and_Scope.html

Comment: Putting weightlb in a function is not the same as putting it in a different module. You might want to do some googling and read up on Python structure.